# Prevent round off in String.format("%.2f", doubleValue) in Java

Tags: java, string, floating-point, format

How do I prevent `String.format("%.2f", doubleValue);` from rounding off (round half up algorithm) instead of just truncating it?

e.g.

```
doubleValue = 123.459
```

after formatting,

```
doubleValue = 123.46
```

I just want to discard the last digit,

```
123.45
```

I know there are other ways to do this, I just want to know if this is possible using the String.format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can always set the rounding mode:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

and then use String.Format()
HALF_EVEN is used by default, but you can change it to CEILING

another no so flexible approach will be (but this is not what you asked about):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
df.format(123.459);
```

Comment: What should you do if the digits on the left of the decimal point can be more than 3 digits? Also, is it possible to use it directly on a double variable that will convert it to a string, instead of creating a new object?

Comment: Future reference this is wrong. If the decimal degits is bellow 6 then  round half up is used, other wise HALF_EVEN rounding is used. I find this absurd!

Comment: I have read the javadocs and done some research and I have not found a way to change the RoundingMode in the String.format() function. Can someone explain it further?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the answer is a big fat NO.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec
"then the value will be rounded using the round half up algorithm"

I find it odd they'd do that, since NumberFormatter allows you to set RoundingMode.  But as you say, there's other ways to do it.  The obviously easiest being subtract .005 from your value first.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @DimitryK's answer implies that you can get String.format() to truncate instead of round, which is untrue.

Answer (score 4):

```
doubleValue = 123.459
doubleValue = Math.ceil(doubleValue*100)/100;
```

Comment: If you want to truncate, don't you want to use `floor` for positive values, and `ceil` for negative ones?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(df.format(123.459));
```

output:

```
123.45
```

> **java.math.RoundingMode.DOWN**
>
> Rounding mode to round towards zero. Never increments the digitprior to a discarded fraction (i.e., truncates). Note that thisrounding mode never increases the magnitude of the calculated value.This mode corresponds to the IEEE 754-2019 rounding-directionattribute roundTowardZero.

Answer (score -4):

use String.format("%.2f", doubleValue - .005)

Comment: Be careful with this approach!. `String.format("%.2f", 1.05 - .005)` results in `1.04`, presumably due to floating point inaccuracies.