# Get file size in activity result in android

Tags: java, android

I have this code  :

```
 public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri fileUri = data.getData();
                File F = new File(fileUri.getPath());
                Log.d("File", "File Uri: " + fileUri.toString());                 
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),activity_file_sharing.class);
                intent.putExtra("Filepath", fileUri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

`F.length()` always return `0` i need to path the size of the selected file to the other activity

can anyone help

Comment: Can I see the other activity where you call setResult()? Also you should call the the super before the switch statement

Comment: are you sure it is a file? does it exist? what is the path like?

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this link:

[how do I get file size of temp file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202805/how-do-i-get-file-size-of-temp-file-in-android)

Try this:

```
File file = new File(selectedPath);
int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()/1024));
```