# How to check files size

Tags: android, list

I have a problem getting the size of a file. 
I have the following code:

```
    File file = new File(path);
    FilenameFilter mediafilefilter = new FilenameFilter(){
        private String[] filter = {".txt"};
        @Override  
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) { 
            for(int i= 0;i< filter.length ; i++){  
                if(filename.indexOf(filter[i]) != -1)return true;  
            } 
            return false; 
        }
     };

     File[] flies = file.listFiles(mediafilefilter);

     if (files != null) {
        {
              if (files.length > 0)
                {
                      System.out.println("Totol is :" + files.length);
                      for (int j = 0; j < files.length; j++) //not work
                 }
        }
     }
```

[some text file is 0 byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQH4C.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I get file size of temp file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202805/how-do-i-get-file-size-of-temp-file-in-android)

Comment: File().length() returns file size you can check with it, also if you wish to display file size in mb you can use  File().length()/(1024*1024) ;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the file size in android sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131930/get-the-file-size-in-android-sdk)

Comment: I try to use :
        int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(files.length/1024));

but I can't build.

Answer (score 1):

Like that

```
list[0].length()/1024
```

list[0] is the first file in your array

Comment: still not bulid.

Comment: what do you mean cant build ?

Comment: double bytes = file.length();

double k = (bytes/1024);

System.out.println("File size = " + k + "KB");



file size always is 4.0 KB

Answer (score 0):

```
   public long getFileSizes(File f) throws Exception{
                long s=0;
                if (f.exists()) {
                 FileInputStream fis = null;
                    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    s= fis.available();
                } 
            return s;
        }
```