# How to find the size of files in kotlin - Android studio

Tags: android, file, kotlin, filesize

I was trying to find the size of the file in kotlin,
using  path.file size . It is crashing with file not found exception.

file.getname is working find and is giving me the file name.

any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's `file.length()`

Answer (score 1):

Us these set of extension functions to get the size.

```
val File.size get() = if (!exists()) 0.0 else length().toDouble()
val File.sizeInKb get() = size / 1024
val File.sizeInMb get() = sizeInKb / 1024
val File.sizeInGb get() = sizeInMb / 1024
val File.sizeInTb get() = sizeInGb / 1024
```

Ref: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10202805/13533028)

Comment: Tried it. its not working .

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to get the file size you can implement your own extension method and other way is

```
 Formatter.formatShortFileSize(context, File(absolutePath).length())
```