# What is the most elegant way in javascript to convert bytes into a readable format

Tags: javascript

I found a very elegant 'humanize' converter for Java on stackoverflow which didn't use any loops.

Is it possible to do the same with javascript?  (e.g 1024 bytes => 1 kb)?

As simple as it sounds I have done quite a search for it

Incase you're wondering : [Java Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java)

Comment: Java or javascript? Also, what is your question?

Comment: Javascript =). The version I found here was for java

Comment: Here's a function to do it:  http://codeaid.net/javascript/convert-size-in-bytes-to-human-readable-format-(javascript)

Comment: Could you paste the link again I get an 'Article not found' when I click that

Comment: Copy paste of link doesn't work, so first hit on this google search - https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS460US460&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=h9&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS460US460&sclient=psy-ab&q=codeaid.net%20convert%20size%20in%20bytes%20to%20human%20readable%20format%20javascript&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=95c2cca83de3aed3&ix=h9&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=653

Comment: I found it.. they have a really nice elegant one in the comments near the bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function byteCount (bytes, unit) {
  if (bytes < (unit = unit || 1000)) 
    return bytes + " B";
  var exp = Math.floor (Math.log (bytes) / Math.log (unit));
  var pre = ' ' +(unit === 1000 ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt (exp - 1) + (unit === 1000 ? "" : "i") + 'B';
    return (bytes / Math.pow (unit, exp)).toFixed (1) + pre;
}

[ 0, 27, 999, 1000, 1023, 1024, 1728, 110592, 7077888, 
  452984832, 28991029248, 1855425871872, 9223372036854775807].forEach (
    function (v) { console.log (v, byteCount (v), byteCount (v, 1024)); });

/* Displays :    
0 "0 B" "0 B"
27 "27 B" "27 B"
999 "999 B" "999 B"
1000 "1.0 kB" "1000 B"
1023 "1.0 kB" "1023 B"
1024 "1.0 kB" "1.0 KiB"
1728 "1.7 kB" "1.7 KiB"
110592 "110.6 kB" "108.0 KiB"
7077888 "7.1 MB" "6.8 MiB"
452984832 "453.0 MB" "432.0 MiB"
28991029248 "29.0 GB" "27.0 GiB"
1855425871872 "1.9 TB" "1.7 TiB"
9223372036854776000 "9.2 EB" "8.0 EiB" */
```

Note the Java version results table has an error displaying 7.1 KB instead of 7.1 MB

Answer (score 0):

There's now a couple of pretty nice Humanize libraries for JS, I'd recommend you have a look at:

#### [HubSpot/Humanize Plus](https://github.com/HubSpot/humanize)

There's also https://github.com/taijinlee/humanize if you'd like to take a look.