# How to make this Java (Android) String substitution?

Tags: java, android, string, substitution, string-substitution

I don't understande why this is not working:
(method is taken from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java) on SO).

```
private String MakeSizeHumanReadable(int bytes, boolean si) {
    int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
    if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
    int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
    String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
    String hr = String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
    hr = hr.replace("-1 B", "n.a.");
    return hr;
}
```

and neither this one:-

```
private String MakeSizeHumanReadable(int bytes, boolean si) {
    int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
    if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
    int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
    String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
    String hr = String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);

    Pattern minusPattern = Pattern.compile("-1 B");
    Matcher minusMatcher = minusPattern.matcher(hr);
    if (minusMatcher.find()) {
        return "n.a.";
    } else {
        return hr;
    }
}
```

from time to time I get `-1 B` from the request (this is normal), that is never changed in `n.a.` (....my question).

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Consider first telling us exactly what you're trying to do with this code.

Comment: thanks for the minus 1. I was just now editing to add the link from SO. You've been light fast. Anyway the line `from time to time I get -1 B from the request (this is normal), that is never changed in n.a. (...my question).` explains that I want to change `-1 B` returned from the linked method in `n.a.`

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking that the piece of code in common by the two blocks explains someway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
```

When `bytes` equals -1 (which is less than `unit` in either case), it returns `-1 B` without ever getting to the line `hr = hr.replace("-1 B", "n.a.");`.

It would be better to have one `return` statement at the end, assign `String hr = bytes + " B"` in the `if`, and add an `else` block around the next three lines. Then after that block, the `hr.replace()` call will execute either way, and then return the value.

Comment: I'm going to try now. Thanks. I don't know why I didn't receive mail notice to your answer!