# Convert byte in user friendly format

Tags: java

I found this code from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java):

```
private static final String[] Q = new String[]{"", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"};

public String getAsString(long bytes)
{
    for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--)
    {
        double step = Math.pow(1024, i);
        if (bytes > step) return String.format("%3.1f %s", bytes / step, Q[i]);
    }
    return Long.toString(bytes);
}
```

I implement this code but the result looks suspicious. I tried to get from JVM how much memory is available and I get only 80 MB. Could you please confirm that this code correctly converts bytes into Megabytes or Gigabytes.

Comment: What results did you get?

Comment: What are you using to get the available memory? What units `GB` or `MB` represent may depend _heavily_ on how you are getting it (unfortunately). One way may use `GB` to represent 1024*1024*1024 bytes, but another way might use `GB` to mean 1000*1024*1024 bytes (1000 MiB) or 1000*1000*1024 bytes (1000000 KiB), or even 1000*1000*1000 bytes, depending. For instance, some hard drive manufacturers use 1GB = 1,000,000,000 bytes, because that lets them label their drives with bigger numbers for cheaper.  The only thing they can't do is use GiB, MiB, or KiB, because those are protected by law.

Comment: The problem for Peter is that he sees only 80Mb of available memory. Code looks correct for 1024*1024*1024.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Try changing `-Xmx`, `-Xms` JVM value when running your app and see the difference.

For example, try running this:

JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2G -Xms2G" java your.Class